# can we use apex:component to show the details of two records

Tags: apex, visualforce-component

vf code :

```
<apex:repeat value="{!strlist}" var="s" id="theRepeat"  >


<c:csample record="{!strlist}"/>
```

controller code:

```
public list<String> getStrlist(){

    id=ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
    system.debug('id'+id);
    strList=id.split(',');
    system.debug(strlist);
    return strlist;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can call the same component twice with different attributes so it will show two different records.

Comment: This is probably a better solution in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You'd need to think about exactly how you'd pass in two Ids if you're going to do it this way though.

Currently, you're using...

```
id=ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
```

... to get the parameter Id. You could quite comfortable do something like this:

```
record1 = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('record1');
record2 = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('record2');
```

Where the URL looks like:

```
mycompany.my.salesforce.com/apex/mypage?record1=abc123&record2=xyz789
```

You could then, easilly query the records (let's assume they're Account records):

```
List<Account> accountList = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Account WHERE Id = :record1 OR Id = :record2];
```

If you're going to have multiple Id's in a single String, you could also do this:

```
List<String> stringList = getStrlist();
List<Account> accountList = new List<Account>();

Account acc1 = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Account WHERE Id = :stringList[0]];
Account acc2 = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Account WHERE Id = :stringList[1]];

accountList.add(acc1);
accountList.add(acc2);
```